# What do we know about "Honorary Aryans" like Milch, Warburg and a few others?

Tags: nazi-germany, jews

The story of special exemptions for very useful Jews or in one case a good friend of Hitler -- these exemptions resulted in people like Milch being able to serve at a very high level in Nazi Germany and again in Milch's case, even be tried for war crimes. What I am wondering is, do we have any indications of what Milch et. al. expected once the war was over? Were they treated just like other non-Jews once exemptions were granted? Were they sometimes able to save Jewish relatives or did they studiously avoid doing anything that would adversely affect their [Aryan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorary_Aryan) status?

Comment: Sources would improve this question.

Comment: Wikipedia articles go somewhat into Milch but I am asking if someone knows more details. Obviously, impossible to know what a victorious Germany would have meant for Milch; I am guessing that given how nazis did things, he would have gradually lost status and maybe ended up with his fellow Jews. I was just reading about Kruschev's life after his fall from power: Initial modest comfort that was arbitrarily diminished.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because speculating on what would have happened after the war to Milch goes into alternate history.

Comment: I asked if we have indications of what he expected, not what we think would happen.

Comment: I think this is a question that would benefit from revision & clarification. This is not a vote to close permanently, it is a vote to request revision.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Milch, his mother declared that his biological father was another man, an Aryan, so he would be treated as Aryan.

In other cases when "honorary Aryan" certificates were issued, they had a provision that the certificate would be reconsidered after the war is over, so all the "honorary Aryans" were to undergo one more selection after the war, possibly, based on their performance during the war.

Comment: Sources would improve this answer.

Comment: @Anixx: This provision, was it actually written on the certificate, like, "To be re-evaluated yearly" or something?

Comment: @Jeff Yes. Not yearly, but after the war.

Comment: @Anixx: So the war itself was mentioned? If so, the clear connotation is that this certificate was an extraordinary thing done due to the emergency of the war. I would guess that the mere presence of this clause was a pretty big hint that its holder was indeed not secure. I could have seen such honoraries living out their post-war lives in something like Tieresenstadt; I find it hard to believe that when the dust has settled they would be just another German.

Comment: @Jeff yes. But it also hinted that everyone would be judged based on their war-time merits. Another case of "selection" which Nazis so much loved. You be loyal and perform good, and we will think what to do with you.

Comment: @Anixx: But every indication is, there was really nothing they could have done given the racist underpinnings. I could see old guys given perhaps comfortable retirement but I bet their offspring weren't going to suddenly be respected Germans. My own life experience tells me that relationships are very transient things, old "grudges" are temporarily forgotten or momentarily overlooked but resurface during calmer times. Note that Emil Maurice was only a quarter Jew, an ancestor from long ago and yet this was *still* a huge problem for him.

Comment: @Jeff actually, they possibly could improve or worsen their case. Even many full-jews could temporarily improve their fates via former performance in WWI or current loyalty. Some people of unpure blood possibly could be tolerated till their natural death and their children, if produced by Aryans could have near-full or full rights. This would depend on Hitler's opinion at the time, nothing was pre-determined intentionally (even who, what ethnicities aryans were was not defined in any law)

Comment: @Anixx -- it is all speculation. But look at Haber or other Jews who had converted, served during WW1 on the front lines, etc. Such Germans I suspect never, ever would reach the point where they were not reminded they were to some extent Jewish.

Comment: @Jeff Haber was a Jew by blood. And even he could earn some benefits compared to other Jews at the time. Yes, his future would be grim under Nazis, but for non-full Jews and especially their offsprings (with 1/8 etc of Jewish blood) it is unclear. Most likely not all of them were going to be killed, Hitler cared more about loyalty (to race) than blood. Slavic children were raised as Germans, and of they somehow managed to learn they were Russian, they would be killed or expelled.

Comment: @Jeff In Poland Hitler ordered to "Germanize" two areas. One governor expelled Poles, the other made Poles to sign that they were in fact Germans forcefully Polonized. There was a compliant on the second governor to Hitler, and he said not to disturb him on minor issues. I suspect those "honorary Aryan" certificates could be re-evaluated after the war by low-ranking officials.

Answer (score 1):

Like all things political, you can get just about anything if you're well connected or very wealthy.

In the case of nazi Germany, the key was a document called an [Aryan Certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aryan_certificate), which was your 'get out of concentration camps free' card. A few very well connected Jews were able to get these, including Milch. With that certificate, they were no longer Jews, but proper Aryans.

Comment: According the the above-mentioned wiki article, Milch had :"...Milch's subsequently being issued, at Göring's urging, a [German Blood Certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Blood_Certificate)". This seems different then your Aryan Certificate.  Can you provide a source that shows Milch had the Aryan Certificate?

Comment: I would suggest that in the same way that ancestors were examined for generations, that contributions during ww1 were discounted eventually, it is a fairly obvious thought that no matter what sort of certificate one had, one's position was not secure. Speculative in the extreme but I bet you Milch's status would have been reexamined after a nazi victory when his skills were no longer required.

Comment: I would also like to comment on the well-connected/wealth providing protection: I do not think this is true. In some cases the extremely wealthy by signing over their assets at a very nominal price were able to buy escape but nothing else. Other times not even that. I am thinking Rothschilds had their property simply confiscated (that was in the reach of the nazis but good and ancient planning had prevented them from reach it all) and they certainly were not able to stop the nazis.